# Efficient RTMP Video Stream Processing in Go: Replacing ffmpeg and OpenCV with WebSockets or WebRTC?

Tags: go, websocket, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I currently have a Go program that retrieves and processes a video stream from an RTMP server by using OpenCV, and then forwards the processed stream to another RTMP server with FFmpeg. While this solution works, I am wondering if there are more efficient approaches leveraging Go modules like WebSockets or WebRTC.

My current implementation involves the following steps:

1. Use OpenCV to connect to the source RTMP server and capture the video stream.
2. Process the images with OpenCV.
3. Use FFmpeg to forward the processed video stream to the destination RTMP server.

Although it gets the job done, I have concerns about the overall efficiency and latency of this setup, especially when dealing with high-resolution video streams.

I've heard about WebSockets and WebRTC as alternatives for real-time video streaming and processing, but I'm not sure how to implement them in Go. Are they more efficient than my current approach? What are the potential benefits and drawbacks of using WebSockets or WebRTC in terms of video stream handling and processing in a Go program?

I'd greatly appreciate any insights, or tips on how to improve the efficiency and real-time performance. Thank you!

Comment: the difference is: websockets and webrtc relate to browsers but RTMP does not.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Just to note that I'm redirecting the stream to Twitch and YouTube channels which use RTMP, I don't know if that changes anything. What would you recommend?